# Search comma separated values in MongoDB using PHP with comma separated input values

Tags: php, mongodb

How to search comma separated values in MongoDB using PHP with comma separated input values?

Ex: In collection1 I am storing the values with comma separated and now I want to search that column with comma separated values:

```
{service_list: 'a, b, c'}
```

Now I want to search that field with (a,d,e).

If we store in array we can search easily but there is no chance to change the DB structure. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try something like that `db.collection1.find({"service_list": /.*a.*.d.*/})`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried just now it's not getting all matched documents

Comment: You _really_ need to change that DB structure. The long-term downside of sticking with a bad database design will outweight the short-term pain of rectifying the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$regex`

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'phpmanual');

$cursor = $collection->find(
 array('service_list' => array('$regex' => 'something'))
);

?>
```